# How to get all available Bluetooth devices after a scan in android?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to put available Bluetooth devices in a listview. I am only able to get paired devices using "Bt_adapter.getBondedDevices()" . But I want to have available devices only. 
I have also tried intent.getParceableExtra() but it is of no use.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `BluetoothAdapter#startDiscovery()` with a registered `IntentFilter`

For example:

```
BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter)
```

where mReceiver is a BroadcastReceiver:

```
mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){
         BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
    }
};
```